# Importing files from another program

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have this program named

> program.py

When i try to import it using the line:

```
import program.py as p
```

it makes an error that no such file exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
.py
```

is used to identify that the program is in Python. To import anything, you only type:

```
import program as p
```

Unless a file or module with the same name exists.